# What should taphold or click-hold do by default?

Tags: click, gestures, tap

**This question is not specific to language/framework/platform.**

I want to know (and confirm), what should happen (by default) if a user taps and holds (or clicks and hold).

***This is more about basic usability and user experience.***

What would a user expect to happen if the user taps(or click) and hold.

For some clarification I did read this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208928

The framework where I need to work on currently triggers holdstart if you hold for more than 400ms, and that in turn triggers tapcancel. I am not happy with it, thus want to know what is the more appropriate default behavior a user would expect.

Comment: FWIW, a tap-and-hold would not behave the same as a click-and-hold. The conventions used in touch-only devices are quite different than a desktop experience.

Answer (score 0):

[Material design](https://material.google.com/patterns/gestures.html#gestures-touch-mechanics) simply says:

> Example: Select an element, such as a list item
>
> Long press is not used to display a contextual menu.

I couldn't find guidelines for iOS IXD but I did find [a page about 3D Touch](https://developer.apple.com/ios/3d-touch/) that seems to show it being used for a contextual menu and a 'quick peek' feature.